Hover classes on multiline calendar events
I have created a calendar that displays events such as holiday for a team. It uses a list with start / end datetime.
I am custom colour coding event types (holiday / parental leave / etc).
I want to keep the colour coding when I select and hover over the event (darkening / lightening as appropriate). I'm using if statements to apply classes (using additionalEventClass formatting) from this list https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/ and have started applying hover classes, for example: ms-bgColor-success--hover
Multiline events, for example this block of two week holiday, are correctly formatted by the --hover classes, both by the above as part of a condition, but also a non conditional ms-fontColor-black--hover, but only the section that I hover. I can hover the first week and the first week will be correctly green with black text on hover, where the second week will default to the purple/purple colour scheme of the calendar itself.
The whole event gets the class "itemHovered" when I hover a portion, but I can't find a way to use this (similar to @isSelected), is there a way to make this work?

